# How to get Ruby SDK Cloudwatch metics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-ruby

I am trying to get CPU metrics from cloudwatch using the Ruby SDK v2 in Rails.

```
metric = Aws::CloudWatch::Metric.new( 'AWS/EC2', 'CPUUtilization', region: 'eu-west-1')


@stats = metric.get_statistics({
  dimensions: [{ :name => 'InstanceID', :value => 'i-14b21212' }],
  start_time: 2.days.ago.utc.iso8601,
  end_time: Time.now.utc.iso8601,
  period: 300,
  statistics: ["Average"]

})
```

This doesn't error, but doesn't return any data points.  I have try this with an instance with advance monitoring enabled and one with out and nothing.

The above returns:

```
[Aws::CloudWatch::Client 200 0.639127 0 retries] get_metric_statistics(dimensions:[{name:"InstanceID",value:"[FILTERED]"}],start_time:2016-12-13 17:17:53 UTC,end_time:2016-12-15 17:17:53 UTC,period:300,statistics:["Average"],namespace:"AWS/EC2",metric_name:"CPUUtilization")

=> #<struct Aws::CloudWatch::Types::GetMetricStatisticsOutput label="CPUUtilization", datapoints=[]>
```

I have also tried this and still get nothing:

```
metric = Aws::CloudWatch::Metric.new( 'AWS/EC2', 'CPUUtilization', region: 'eu-west-1')


@stats = metric.get_statistics({
  dimensions: [{ :name => 'InstanceID', :value => 'i-14b21212' }],
  start_time: 2.days.ago.utc.iso8601,
  end_time: Time.now.utc.iso8601,
  period: 300,
  extended_statistics: ["p10", "p20", "p30", "p40", "p50", "p60", "p70", "p80", "p90", "p100"]

})
```

Any help on what I am doing wrong would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html):

> Metric filters are case sensitive.

So this would be the correct call:

> dimensions: [{ :name => '**InstanceId**', :value => 'i-14b21212' }],